# Adding a forward slash to the end of my URLs is breaking them

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to add a forward slash to the end of all my URL's....

Currently, an example link on my website is:  `<a href="/about/terms-of-use">`

I'm getting an Internal Server Error when I change this to:  `<a href="/about/terms-of-use/">`

Here is my htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html  [L]
```

Why would the trailing forward slash be breaking the URL's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is breaking because (for your example) you get something like: terms-of-use/.html
Try this instead:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.html  [L]
```

This will remove the last slash from the request, and then rewrite it to the appropriate file.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now when I go to: <a href="/about/terms-of-use"> (with no trailing slash) I get a "Not Found" error.  How can I make it so that a user can enter either URL, but always be directed to the one with the trailing slash?